# Deploy fail status on Netlify but site still deploys

Tags: r, blogdown, netlify

I am using `blogdown` to make my first site and am trying to follow the instructions for deployment in the online documentation for `blogdown`[[here]](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/deployment.html)

This is what I understood from the documentation, build the site in RStudio and copy the contents of the `public` folder in a git repository. The repository [sn248.github.io](https://github.com/sn248/sn248.github.io) used to contain the contents for my `jekyll` based static web page and was hosted using Github pages. It had only a few posts, which I am planning to manually convert into `blogdown` based webite.

I do see my new website with the theme I want, but I am worried about the deploy failed message I see on Netlify (below)

```
12:09:21 AM: Installing Hugo 0.30
12:09:24 AM: Error: Unable to locate Config file. Perhaps you need to create a new site.
       Run `hugo help new` for details. (Config File "config" Not Found in "[/opt/build/repo]")
12:09:25 AM: Build complete: exit code: 255
12:09:25 AM: Cleaning up docker container
12:09:25 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 255
12:09:26 AM: An error occurred while building the site, skipping the deploy and cache refresh.
12:09:26 AM: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 255
12:09:26 AM: Finished processing build request in 13.85761953s
```

I have specified my `Build command:`as `hugo` and my `Publish Directory:` as `public`. I have tried with the `HUGO_VERSION` `0.24.1` (as shown in the documentation) also but got the same result. Looking at the error message it seems I am missing a basic step here. But I also don't understand how anything got built if the Config file was not located.

Link to my [Git repo](https://github.com/sn248/sn248.github.io)

Link to my [Site](https://sn248.github.io/)

Any help here would be highly appreciated, thanks!
SN248

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Github repo contains a *prebuilt* website, and you should not use `hugo` to build it again on Netlify. Please read [the documentation on Netlify](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/netlify.html) in the **blogdown** book. To quote the relevant part in the book:

> [...] you can certainly prebuild your website using any tools, push it to GitHub, and Netlify is still able to deploy it for you. What you need to do is to **leave the build command empty**, and tell Netlify your publish directory (e.g., Hugo's default `public/`, but if your prebuilt website is under the root directory, **specify `.` as the publish directory** instead).

Comment: Thank you very much!! I obviously didn't read that part thoroughly, the site now deploys without any error messages. It seems however, my understanding of how to deploy a site is misplaced. I will read the deployment chapter again to see what should I change so that I can deploy the way it is written in the book. I might post a newbie question again, but thanks for your answer and all of your wonderful work which makes building sites for users like us easy!

Comment: You are welcome! As I said in this post, newbie questions are absolutely fine to me: https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/09/11/announcing-blogdown/